# Estimated tax paid form from IRS?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

I made a one-time estimated tax payment in June 2022. When filing my taxes for tax year 2022, will I get a form in the mail from IRS (like I do with my W2 from my employer), showing exactly how much taxes I already paid during the year and what quarter it was paid? Or, would I have to keep track of this myself and file appropriately?

Comment: A side note... definitely check the website even if you have an email confirmation AND a transfer from your bank account. I know people (myself included) who are having payments not show up for 2022 (seems like Q3 estimated payments are the main ones having issues).

Answer (score 9):

No, those payments need to be self-tracked.

If you made payments online or by IRS Direct Pay, you should have received an email confirmation of the payment *request*. This doesn't confirm successful payments.

You can go to [the IRS' website](https://www.irs.gov/payments/your-online-account) and log into your online account (you may need to create one). There's a "payment activity" section that shows your pending, scheduled, and confirmed payments.

[image: IRS.gov Payment Activity page]

Comment: Got it...I wonder, if I had forgotten to report the estimated taxes I already paid, and end up overpaying in taxes when I file, will IRS notice that and send me a refund, or I would just overpay taxes without anyone noticing?

Comment: They may notice and automatically reconcile it, but if they don't, you'll want to file an amended return with the correct info.

Comment: In addition to IRS' online (web) account, they have a smartphone app, AND you can request (by web, phone, or mail) that an account transcript be mailed to you. Plus if you pay _from_ a bank or credit card (I don't recommend the latter because it costs extra, but the option exists) every such account I have or have ever had provides(d) monthly statements, which you _should_ look at and usually keep for a while, and today all of them all have websites which you/I can just look at _or_ download the data.